# create a certificate in Cert:\LocalMachine\My from existing certificate without cloning directly

Tags: powershell-2.0, x509certificate2, pfx

I would like to create a new certificate from existing certificate by probably using the New-SelfSignedCertificate, but would not like to use the -clone property.

currently

```
Import-PfxCertificate -Exportable -FilePath encryption.pfx -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $securePwd | out-null;
```

Then use the below to create a new cert

```
Set-Location -Path "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
$OldCert = (Get-ChildItem -Path thumbprint)
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CloneCert $OldCert
```

I would like to skip the process of import and -clonecert, but instead may be look at cert directly and get the properties, is it possible to do that?

Comment: What is $OldCert here ? Are looking for code to get certificate attributes of encryption.pfx ?

Comment: I am looking to create a cert on the fly using powershell similar to the one I already have/downloading